# Install error (--site-dirs) python 2.6 and setuptools

Tags: python, linux, installation, setuptools

i can't install setuptools on my nas.
i have this error :

```
LeGrappin> python2.6 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
LeGrappin> python2.6 setup.py install
running install
error: /opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages (in --site-dirs) is not on sys.path
LeGrappin>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It's warning you that the place it is getting installed to will not be a place where python loads modules from.

To check which directories are, simply start python, then run

```
import sys; print sys.path
```

That should give you all directories that do work.  You may have to override the installation prefix as an argument to install.